# when all fields are empty, echo and exit - by newbie

Tags: php

Please tell me what needs to be done, to avoid the message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /xxxx/xxxxxxx/public_html/contact-    it/feedback.php on line xxx (the last line of feedback.php = ?>)
```

Thanks to all for any hint.

```
if(empty($data_start)) { 
    if(empty($data_end)) { 
        if(empty($comment)) { 
        # all empty 
echo "You have not specified any details to submit to us";
    exit ;

?>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and format the code with the 'code block' button (the button with all the 1's and 0's)?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing curly braces:

```
if(empty($data_start)) { 
    if(empty($data_end)) { 
        if(empty($comment)) { 
        # all empty 
echo "You have not specified any details to submit to us";
    exit();
}}}
```

You should re-factor your code like this:

```
if(empty($data_start) && empty($data_end) && empty($comment)){
    exit("You have not specified any details to submit to us");
}
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_operators.asp

Comment: Sarfraz - have re-factored the code and works fine ! I assumed there must be some && function, but ... newbie. Well, again: Thanks. Good lesson for me ! :-))

Comment: Sarfraz - can I bother you once more ? I promise won't come backafter that - except with a "thanks". Have extended the code a bit: When 'data_start' and 'data_end is given, but no 'pax', there should be a message:

Comment: }

if(empty($data_start) && empty($data_end) && empty($comment)){ 
    exit("You have not specified any details to submit to us. <br>Please use your browser to go back to the form"); 
} 
  # arrival, departure and comments empty 

  
if(!isset($data_start) && if(!isset($data_end)) &&  if(empty($pax)){
      exit("Please tell us the number of persons in your group. <br>Please use your browser to go back to the form"); 
} 
  # arrival, departure given, but pax empty

Comment: resolves in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /xxxx/xxxxx/contact-it/feedback.php on line 71

Comment: @Frank: You should edit your main question again with anything you want to add :)

Comment: OK: I have 3 fields:
arrival, departure and no of persons (pax)
When arrival (date_start) is entered and departure (date_end) is entered, there should be an entry in the field "pax" as well. If not, there should be a message: "please tell us the number..."

Comment: exit statements don't need brackets http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php